# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'env_id' in 'field list': INSERT INTO {apachesolr_stats}

Tags: database, search

I get this error a lot in the drupal logs. Several times an hour.  Anyone know why, what the impact is, and how to fix it?

My config:

- Acquia Drupal 7.36
- Running in IIS 7.5 / Windows Server 2008
- Solr 4.6
- PHP 5.3

Error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'env_id' in 'field list': INSERT INTO {apachesolr_stats}
>   (timestamp, uid, sid, numfound, showed_suggestions, total_time,
>   prepare_time, process_time, page, keywords, filters, sort, env_id,
>   page_id) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1423845337 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =>
>   697523 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [:db_insert_placeholder_3]
>   => 35 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 15 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 15 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => question
>   about bill [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => a:0:{}
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_11] =>
>   a:2:{s:5:"#name";s:5:"score";s:10:"#direction";s:4:"desc";}
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => solr [:db_insert_placeholder_13] =>
>   core_search ) in apachesolr_stats_exit() (line 191 of
>   D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\apachesolr_stats\apachesolr_stats.module).

**UPDATE**:

I am running apachesolr_stats v. 7.x-1.0-beta1

Running update.php produces this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in apachesolr_stats_block_info() (line 961 of D:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\apachesolr_stats\apachesolr_stats.module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your drupal database, table apachesolr_stats if it has a field env_id.

If not check installation of module apachesolr_stats, maybe uninstall and reinstall. It should create that table apachesolr_stats with the field env_id.

Comment: check your version of apachesolr_stats, field env_id got added in beta1. Maybe you missed update.php once in a while.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it is definitely the source of the problem.  However the update.php solution didn't fix it (see update)  I don't have access to the DB so I can't check the table, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you could try to uninstall and reinstall the module and see if that fixes the problem. You will probably lose the entries in the table apachesolr_stats when you do that. If you have no DB access and backup possibility for DB this could be risky.